# UICollectionView custom button actions in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have used UICollectionView and I am populating it with results from API. There is a ID, Image, Name, Description and Liked true or false coming in API.
I have implemented all these things and now all the results loads inside this collection view.

```
    extension VCResCourses : UICollectionViewDelegate {

}

extension VCResCourses: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let length = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16)
        return CGSize(width: length, height: 135);
    }
}

extension VCResCourses : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSources.numbeOfRowsInEachGroup(section)
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let currentCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier,for:indexPath) as! CVCResCourse

    let doCourses: [DOCourses] = dataSources.total()
    let doCourse = doCourses[indexPath.row]

    let courseId = doCourse.Id!
    var courseName = doCourse.Name!
    let courseAddress = doCourse.Address!
    let courseImage = doCourse.Image!
    let courseWish = doCourse.Wish!

    courseName = courseName.replacingOccurrences(of: "\t", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)

    currentCell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: courseImage))
    currentCell.textPrimary.text = courseName.capitalized
    currentCell.textSecondary.text = courseAddress.capitalized
    currentCell.buttonOpen.addTarget(...)
    currentCell.buttonFav.addTarget(...)

    return currentCell
    }
}
```

What I am trying now is there are two button on each CELL one opens details of the record and other set favourite to true or false.

Now I need to get id of the current record and toggle its favourite state to true or false or open the detail page using the id. I am not able to add action for buttons and perform the favourite or open detail action using ID.

In android I have done this by adding clickListener inside CustomBaseAdapter which perform actions for each row or record of the data. I need to do the same in iOS as well but no luck yet

I am new to iOS development please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set `tag` for each button for e,g

```
currentCell.buttonOpen.tag = indexPath.row
currentCell.buttonFav.tag = indexPath.row
currentCell.buttonOpen.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and you can get id via button.tag, for e.g

```
func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let doCourses: [DOCourses] = dataSources.total()
  let doCourse = doCourses[sender.tag]
 let courseId = doCourse.Id!
  print (courseId)
}
```